# In Delphi can a TADOStoredProc be executed in a BeginTrans/CommitTrans?

Tags: database, delphi, ado

We currently have a service that does a loop that loads a TADOStoredProc (via StoredProc.Parameters.CreateParameter) and then does an ExecProc to insert it into our table.

Is there a way I can wrap that whole loop inside a TADOConnection.BeginTrans and then finish it with a ADOConnection.CommitTrans?  Basically I wish to do a batch insert.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, stored procedures can be called inside of a transaction, and any records inserted/deleted/modified will not be applied to the database until the transaction is committed, eg:

```pascal
ADOConnection1.BeginTrans;
try
  // execute TADOStoredProc as many times as you need...
  ADOConnection1.CommitTrans;
except
  ADOConnection1.RollbackTrans;
  raise;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Remy - good to see your name.  I'll still need to remove ExecProc it looks like.